# Finding out which ports a process listens to via PHP

Tags: php, winapi, com

I have a windows server running PHP+Apache

A PHP script watches certain processes (I have a list of PIDs), and I can use several Win32 APIs to find out a couple of things about them.

For instance:

```
$obj    = new COM('winmgmts://localhost/root/CIMV2');
$list   = $obj->ExecQuery('Select * from Win32_Process');
foreach($list as $item){
    echo $item->CommandLine,"\n";
}
```

Some processes listen on some ports, and I want to find out which process is listening on which port.

I've searched around a bit and read that the methods `GetExtendedTcpTable` and `GetExtendedUdpTable` can help me with this. I've read that those are also part of the win32 APIs, however, I have no idea how I could call those methods from PHP (or if it's even possible at all).

I've also read about `netstat -a -b -n`, which I could call with the `exec` function, but I think that asking it via a Win32 API would be much cleaner and faster than parsing the output of a command line program.

Answer (score 0):

There is an experimental function: [w32api_invoke_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.w32api-invoke-function.php) which may help you calling GetExtendedTcpTable.